# Gaming laptop to buy?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, gaming

I have been looking to buy an GTX 10 series laptops, for the last month here in India, I need a laptop which would be able to play games on Med-High settings in the upcoming 4+ years.

I have browsed Amazon.com and many products are not available in India.

What I have in mind is:

2170 USD(140000 INR)
HP OMEN - 17 inch - i7 7th Gen - GTX 1060TX - 256 SSD
http://www.hpshopping.in/hp_omen_-_17-w249tx

1550 USD(100000 INR)
HP OMEN - 15.6 inch - i7 7th Gen - GTX 1050Ti - 256 SSD
http://www.hpshopping.in/omen_by_hp_15-ax252tx_laptop_pc

I will probably get a monitor later, If I get the 15 inch one.

Which one would be the best, Also feel free to suggest some other choices, but I feel these are best within this range.

Thanks.

Comment: These choices aren't too bad. they'll hold their own on high end games for a whlie. I would try to check if there are cheaper places to buy this laptop like [online sources](https://www.newegg.com/) avoid anything retail (best buy) or buying directly from the source if you want the best price. Honestly though, self building a desktop will allow you to get the greatest bang for buck and build your computer [exactly as you want it](https://pcpartpicker.com/).

Comment: @BennettYeo, pcpartpicker.com is great, but not relly meant for laptops, which the OP is looking for.

Comment: Curious, if you are spending that much for a gaming laptop and plan on directing output to a monitor, why don't you build a desktop PC?

Comment: I was just checking the specs here, I would probably buy it offline for any lower prices if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not from India, and INR prices don't translate very well in my mind, but [this](https://www.flipkart.com/acer-aspire-vx-core-i7-7th-gen-8-gb-1-tb-hdd-128-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-4-graphics-15-notebook/p/itmeshbcnh7fnhz8) seems about in your price range.

I am not sure that this would be available to ship to you (since I am not from India), but it seems that Flipkart is pretty big out there, so hopefully it is.

Anyways, this is considerably less powerful than the laptop you posted, but seems to also be somewhat cheaper. The CPU is the same, but the GPU is a 1050 (not Ti) instead of a 1060. It has 8GB of RAM instead of 16GB. I have a laptop with similar specifications to the one listed (better only in terms of RAM), and it performs very well. If you want to game in 1080p without anything like VR and don't always need the absolute highest settings, this should be adequate.

There is a [US version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N12YZ7B) of this notebook that has a better GPU for a really good price, but I was unable to locate this on any Indian site.

Good luck finding something that works for you.

Comment: Hey, now I am even considering going for the GTX 1070 TX laptop, but 4k version is not available in India, it has 1080p with 1070TX, and I think, later if I go for a 4k monitor, 1070TX won't be able to handle it at ultra anyway, so should I stick with the 1080p + 1060 6GB ?, to play games for next 4 years at med-ultra ?

Comment: @NikhilVerma 1080p with a 1060 6GB is a great combination; it should continue to run games for the next 4 years. You should be able to run most games at high to ultra settings at first, and after 4 years have passed the majority of games should run on at least medium settings. Take a look at the GTX 560 Ti, for example, which is around 5 years old now. It isn't great compared to what is available now, but by no means is it useless for gaming (yet). Unfortunately the laptop I recommended, while cheaper than many others, only has a GTX 1050, so I would recommend better if possible.

Comment: Yep, I think 1060 would be best.

Answer (score 0):

This MSI (from Amazon India) is a 17" and with the 8GB of 1070 graphic goodness, it is even more powerful than the 17" HP in your link. And the RGB keyboard isn't bad at all. But it is more expensive too.

http://www.amazon.in/dp/B01N6QUGZO/ref=sr_1_5?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1496117351&sr=1-5

---

This one is also something worth taking a look at. It is similarly specced to the 17" HP (which is a lot better than the 15" you linked).

http://www.amazon.in/MSI-GE62VR-7RF-Apache-Pro/dp/B01NAKTV53/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1496117103&sr=1-2

Comment: I need something below 1500 USD, The 2nd one has the price of 17 inch hp one. Thanks anyway!